# ActiveRecord select through multiple HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

What's the most efficient way to get all the channels (with no duplicates) for a particular user?

So effectively:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM users
  JOIN groups_users ON users.id=groups_users.user_id
  JOIN channels_groups ON groups_users.group_id=channels_groups.group_id
  JOIN channels ON channels_groups.channel_id=channels.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
user = User.first
channels = user.groups.flat_map(&:channels).uniq
```

Comment: I love ruby. Thanks for that and the &: shortcut.

Comment: Just a note, uniq! returns nil if no changes were made. uniq works fine in this instance however.